# any way to stop unaligned access from c++ standard library on x86_64?

Tags: linux, debugging, x86, memory-alignment

I am trying to check for any unaligned reads in my program.  I enable unaligned access processor exception via (using x86_64 on g++ on linux kernel 3.19):

```
asm volatile("pushf \n"
             "pop %%rax \n"
             "or $0x40000, %%rax \n"
             "push %%rax \n"
             "popf \n" ::: "rax");
```

I do an optional forced unaligned read which triggers the exception so i know its working.  After i disable that I get an error in a piece of code which otherwise seems fine :

```
char fullpath[eMaxPath];
    snprintf(fullpath, eMaxPath, "%s/%s", "blah", "blah2");
```

the stacktrace shows a failure via `__memcpy_sse2` which leads me to suspect that the standard library is using sse to fulfill my memcpy but it doesnt realize that i have now made unaligned reads unacceptable.

Is my thinking correct and is there any way around this (ie can i make the standard library use an unaligned safe sprintf/memcpy instead)?

thanks

Comment: Be careful with `push`/`pop` in inline asm. It's not safe when the ABI includes a [red-zone below the stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_zone_(computing)) (like x86-64 SysV does), because [gcc assumes that asm statements don't clobber the red-zone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34522750/224132). It will corrupt anything that gcc spilled there.  With a red-zone, I think you'd just have to `add $-128, %rsp` before using the stack, or use a reg to save/restore the stack memory you're about to clobber. You can declare a register clobber, but you can't declare a `-8(%rsp)` clobber :/

Comment: So maybe `asm("add $-128, %rsp ; pushf ; orl $0x40000, (%rsp); popf; sub $-128, %rsp");` Or even `orb $0x4, 2(%rsp)` to save two bytes :P. You could use `orq` to avoid a store-forwarding stall when `popf` reads 8 bytes.  I know this isn't something that needs to get optimized, but the unnecessary load/store into rax jumped out at me. (using pop instead of mov is actually fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I commented on the question, that asm isn't safe, because it [steps on the red-zone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522750/224132).  Instead, use

```
asm volatile ("add $-128, %rsp\n\t"
    "pushf\n\t"
    "orl $0x40000, (%rsp)\n\t"
    "popf\n\t"
    "sub $-128, %rsp\n\t"
    );
```

(`-128` fits in a sign-extended 8bit immediate, but `128` doesn't, hence using `add $-128` to subtract 128.)

Or in this case, there are dedicated instructions for toggling that bit, like there are for the carry and direction flags:

```
asm("stac");   // Set AC flag
asm("clac");   // Clear AC flag
```

---

It's a good idea to have some idea when your code uses unaligned memory.  It's not necessarily a good idea to change your code to avoid it in every case.  Sometimes better locality from packing data closer together is more valuable.

Given that you shouldn't necessarily aim to eliminate all unaligned accesses anyway, I don't think this is the easiest way to find the ones you do have.

modern x86 hardware has fast hardware support for unaligned loads/stores.  When they don't span a cache-line boundary, or lead to store-forwarding stalls, there's literally no penalty.

What you might try is looking at performance counters for some of these events:

```
  misalign_mem_ref.loads     [Speculative cache line split load uops dispatched to L1 cache]
  misalign_mem_ref.stores    [Speculative cache line split STA uops dispatched to L1 cache]

  ld_blocks.store_forward    [This event counts loads that followed a store to the same address, where the data could not be forwarded inside the pipeline from the store to the load.
                             The most common reason why store forwarding would be blocked is when a load's address range overlaps with a preceeding smaller uncompleted store.
                             See the table of not supported store forwards in the Intel? 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual.
                             The penalty for blocked store forwarding is that the load must wait for the store to complete before it can be issued.]
```

(from [`ocperf.py list` output](http://halobates.de/blog/p/245) on my Sandybridge CPU).

There are probably other ways to detect unaligned memory access.  Maybe valgrind?  I searched on [valgrind detect unaligned](https://www.google.ca/?q=valgrind%20detect%20unaligned) and found [this mailing list discussion from 13 years ago](http://valgrind-users.narkive.com/3kYSpyqK/valgrind-detection-of-non-aligned-memory-accesses).  Probably still not implemented.

---

The hand-optimized library functions do use unaligned accesses because it's the fastest way for them to get their job done.  e.g. copying bytes 6 to 13 of a string to somewhere else can and should be done with just a single 8-byte load/store.

So yes, you would need special slow&safe versions of library functions.

---

If your code would have to execute extra instructions to avoid using unaligned loads, it's often not worth it.  Esp. if the input is *usually* aligned, having a loop that does the first up-to-alignment-boundary elements before starting the main loop may just slow things down.  In the aligned case, everything works optimally, with no overhead of checking alignment.  In the unaligned case, things might work a few percent slower, but as long as the unaligned cases are rare, it's not worth avoiding them.

Esp. if it's not SSE code, since non-AVX legacy SSE can only fold loads into memory operands for ALU instructions when alignment is guaranteed.

The benefit of having good-enough hardware support for unaligned memory ops is that software can be faster in the aligned case.  It can leave alignment-handling to hardware, instead of running extra instructions to handle pointers that are probably aligned.  (Linus Torvalds had some interesting posts about this on the http://realworldtech.com/ forums, but they're not searchable so I can't find it.

Comment: yeah , following an example from another question im trying to go down the path of checking the misalign_mem_refs.loads via perf assuming i can get perf to work on my system and assuming i can get it to properly report the counter for unaligned access which i think is r0105

Comment: @skimon: `ocperf.py` is a nice wrapper that gives you symbolic names for more uarch-specific events.  That's why I linked it.

Answer (score 3):

While I hate to discourage an admirable notion, you're playing with fire, my friend.

It's not merely `sse2` access but *any* unaligned access. Even a simple `int` fetch.

---

Here's a test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void *intptr;

void
require_aligned(void)
{
    asm volatile("pushf \n"
             "pop %%rax \n"
             "or $0x00040000, %%eax \n"
             "push %%rax \n"
             "popf \n" ::: "rax");
}

void
relax_aligned(void)
{
    asm volatile("pushf \n"
             "pop %%rax \n"
             "andl $0xFFFBFFFF, %%eax \n"
             "push %%rax \n"
             "popf \n" ::: "rax");
}

void
msg(const char *str)
{
    int len;

    len = strlen(str);
    write(1,str,len);
}

void
grab(void)
{
    volatile int x = *(int *) intptr;
}

int
main(void)
{

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    // minimum alignment from malloc is [usually] 8
    intptr = malloc(256);
    printf("intptr=%p\n",intptr);

    // normal access to aligned pointer
    msg("normal\n");
    grab();

    // enable alignment check exception
    require_aligned();

    // access aligned pointer under check [will be okay]
    msg("aligned_norm\n");
    grab();

    // this grab will generate a bus error
    intptr += 1;
    msg("aligned_except\n");
    grab();

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this is:

```
intptr=0x1996010
normal
aligned_norm
aligned_except
Bus error (core dumped)
```

The program generated this simply because of an attempted 4 byte `int` fetch from address `0x1996011` [which is *odd* and *not* a multiple of 4].

So, once you turn on the AC [alignment check] flag, even simple things will break.

---

IMO, if you truly have some things that are not aligned *optimally* and are trying to find them, using `printf`, instrumenting your code with debug asserts, or using `gdb` with some special `watch` commands or breakpoints with condition statements are a better/safer way to go

---

**UPDATE:**

> I a using my own custom allocator am preparing my code to run on an architecture that doesnt suport unaligned read/writes so I want to make sure my code will not break on that architecture.

Fair enough.

*Side note:* My curiousity has gotten the better of me as the only [major] arches I can recall [at the moment] that have this issue are Motorola `mc68000` and older IBM mainframes (e.g. IBM `System 370`).

One practical reason for my curiosity is that for certain arches (e.g. ARM/android, MIPS) there are emulators available. You could rebuild the emulator from source, adding any extra checks, if needed. Otherwise, doing your debugging under the emulator might be an option.

> I can trap unaligned read/write using either the asm , or via gdb but both cause SIGBUS which i cant continue from in gdb and im getting too many false positives from std library (in the sense that their implementation would be aligned access only on the target).

I can tell you from experience that trying to resume from a signal handler after this doesn't work too well [if at all]. Using `gdb` is the best bet if you can eliminate the false positives by having AC *off* in the standard functions [see below].

> Ideally i guess i would like to use something like perf to show me callstacks that have misaligned but so far no dice.

This is possible, but you'd have to verify that `perf` even reports them. To see, you could try `perf` against my original test program above. If it works, the "counter" should be zero before and one after.

---

The cleanest way may be to pepper your code with "assert" macros [that can be compiled in and out with a `-DDEBUG` switch].

However, since you've gone to the trouble of laying the groundwork, it may be worthwhile to see if the AC method can work.

Since you're trying to debug *your* memory allocator, you only need AC on in *your* functions. If one of your functions calls `libc`, disable AC, call the function, and then reenable AC.

A memory allocator is fairly low level, so it can't rely on too many standard functions. Most standard functions rely on being able to call malloc. So, you might also want to consider a vtable interface to the rest of the [standard] library.

I've coded some slightly different AC bit set/clear functions. I put them into a `.S` function to eliminate inline asm hassles.

I've coded up a simple sample usage in three files.

Here are the AC set/clear functions:

```
// acbit/acops.S -- low level AC [alignment check] operations

#define AC_ON       $0x00040000
#define AC_OFF      $0xFFFFFFFFFFFBFFFF

    .text

// acpush -- turn on AC and return previous mask
    .globl  acpush
acpush:
    // get old mask
    pushfq
    pop     %rax

    mov     %rax,%rcx                   // save to temp
    or      AC_ON,%ecx                  // turn on AC bit

    // set new mask
    push    %rcx
    popfq

    ret

// acpop -- restore previous mask
    .globl  acpop
acpop:
    // get current mask
    pushfq
    pop     %rax

    and     AC_OFF,%rax                 // clear current AC bit

    and     AC_ON,%edi                  // isolate the AC bit in argument
    or      %edi,%eax                   // lay it in

    // set new mask
    push    %rax
    popfq

    ret

// acon -- turn on AC
    .globl  acon
acon:
    jmp     acpush

// acoff -- turn off AC
    .globl  acoff
acoff:
    // get current mask
    pushfq
    pop     %rax

    and     AC_OFF,%rax                 // clear current AC bit

    // set new mask
    push    %rax
    popfq

    ret
```

Here is a header file that has the function prototypes and some "helper" macros:

```
// acbit/acbit.h -- common control

#ifndef _acbit_acbit_h_
#define _acbit_acbit_h_

#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef unsigned long flags_t;

#define VARIABLE_USED(_sym) \
    do { \
        if (1) \
            break; \
        if (!! _sym) \
            break; \
    } while (0)

#ifdef ACDEBUG
#define ACPUSH \
    do { \
        flags_t acflags = acpush()

#define ACPOP \
        acpop(acflags); \
    } while (0)

#define ACEXEC(_expr) \
    do { \
        acoff(); \
        _expr; \
        acon(); \
    } while (0)
#else
#define ACPUSH          /**/
#define ACPOP           /**/
#define ACEXEC(_expr)   _expr
#endif

void *intptr;

flags_t
acpush(void);

void
acpop(flags_t omsk);

void
acon(void);

void
acoff(void);

#endif
```

Here is a sample program that uses all of the above:

```
// acbit/acbit2 -- sample allocator

#include <acbit.h>

// mymalloc1 -- allocation function [raw calls]
void *
mymalloc1(size_t len)
{
    flags_t omsk;
    void *vp;

    // function prolog
    // NOTE: do this on all "outer" (i.e. API) functions
    omsk = acpush();

    // do lots of stuff ...
    vp = NULL;

    // encapsulate standard library calls like this to prevent false positives:
    acoff();
    printf("%p\n",vp);
    acon();

    // function epilog
    acpop(omsk);

    return vp;
}

// mymalloc2 -- allocation function [using helper macros]
void *
mymalloc2(size_t len)
{
    void *vp;

    // function prolog
    ACPUSH;

    // do lots of stuff ...
    vp = NULL;

    // encapsulate standard library calls like this to prevent false positives:
    ACEXEC(printf("%p\n",vp));

    // function epilog
    ACPOP;

    return vp;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int x;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    // minimum alignment from malloc is [usually] 8
    intptr = mymalloc1(256);
    intptr = mymalloc2(256);

    x = *(int *) intptr;

    return x;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

> I like the idea of disabling the check before any library calls.

If the AC H/W works and you wrap the library calls, this should yield *no* false positives. The only exception would be if the compiler made a call to *its* internal helper library (e.g. doing 64 bit divide on 32 bit machine, etc.).

Be aware/wary of the ELF loader (e.g. `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`) doing dynamic symbol resolution on "lazy" bindings of symbols. Shouldn't be a big problem. There are ways to force the relocations to occur at program start, if necessary.

> I have given up on perf for this as it seems to show me garbage even for a simple program like the one you wrote.

The perf code in the kernel is complex enough that it may be more trouble than it's worth. It has to communicate with the perf program with a pipe [IIRC]. Also, doing the AC thing is [probably] uncommon enough that the kernel's code path for this isn't well tested.

> Im using ocperf with misalign_mem_ref.loads and stores but either way the counters dont correlate at all. If i record and look at the callstacks i get completely unrecognizable callstacks for these counters so i suspect either the counter doesnt work on my hardware/perf or it doesnt actually count what i think it counts

I honestly don't know if perf handles process reschedules to different cores properly [or not]--it should [IMO]. But, using `sched_setaffinity` to lock your program to a single core might help.

But, using the AC bit is more direct and definitive, IMO. I think that's the better bet.

---

I've talked about adding "assert" macros in the code.

I've coded some up below. These are what I'd use. They are independent of the AC code. But, they can also be used in conjunction with the AC bit code in a *"belt and suspenders"* approach.

These macros have one distinct advantage. When properly [and liberally] inserted, they can check for bad pointer values at the time they're *calculated*. That is, much closer to the true source of the problem.

With AC, you may calculate a bad value, but AC only kicks in [sometime] later, when the pointer is *dereferenced* [which may not happen in your API code at all].

I've done a complete memory allocator before [with overrun checks and "guard" pages, etc.]. The macro approach is what I used. And, if I had only one tool for this, it is the one I'd use. So, I recommend it above all else.

But, as I said, it can be used with the AC code as well.

Here's the header file for the macros:

```
// acbit/acptr.h -- alignment check macros

#ifndef _acbit_acptr_h_
#define _acbit_acptr_h_

#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

// bit mask for given width
#define ACMSKOFWID(_wid) \
    ((1u << (_wid)) - 1)

#ifdef ACDEBUG2
#define ACPTR_MSK(_ptr,_msk) \
    acptrchk(_ptr,_msk,__FILE__,__LINE__)
#else
#define ACPTR_MSK(_ptr,_msk)        /**/
#endif

#define ACPTR_WID(_ptr,_wid) \
    ACPTR_MSK(_ptr,(_wid) - 1)

#define ACPTR_TYPE(_ptr,_typ) \
    ACPTR_WID(_ptr,sizeof(_typ))

// acptrfault -- pointer alignment fault
void
acptrfault(const void *ptr,const char *file,int lno);

// acptrchk -- check pointer for given alignment
static inline void
acptrchk(const void *ptr,u32 msk,const char *file,int lno)
{
#ifdef ACDEBUG2

#if ACDEBUG2 >= 2
    printf("acptrchk: TRACE ptr=%p msk=%8.8X file='%s' lno=%d\n",
        ptr,msk,file,lno);
#endif

    if (((unsigned long) ptr) & msk)
        acptrfault(ptr,file,lno);
#endif
}

#endif
```

Here's the "fault" handler function:

```
// acbit/acptr -- alignment check macros

#include <acbit/acptr.h>
#include <acbit/acbit.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// acptrfault -- pointer alignment fault
void
acptrfault(const void *ptr,const char *file,int lno)
{

    // NOTE: it's easy to set a breakpoint on this function

    printf("acptrfault: pointer fault -- ptr=%p file='%s' lno=%d\n",
        ptr,file,lno);

    exit(1);
}
```

And, here's a sample program that uses them:

```
// acbit/acbit3 -- sample allocator using check macros

#include <acbit.h>
#include <acptr.h>

static double static_array[20];

// mymalloc3 -- allocation function
void *
mymalloc3(size_t len)
{
    void *vp;

    // get something valid
    vp = static_array;

    // do lots of stuff ...
    printf("BEF vp=%p\n",vp);

    // check pointer
    // NOTE: these can be peppered after every [significant] calculation
    ACPTR_TYPE(vp,double);

    // do something bad ...
    vp += 1;
    printf("AFT vp=%p\n",vp);

    // check again -- this should fault
    ACPTR_TYPE(vp,double);

    return vp;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int x;

    setlinebuf(stdout);

    // minimum alignment from malloc is [usually] 8
    intptr = mymalloc3(256);

    x = *(int *) intptr;

    return x;
}
```

Here's the program output:

```
BEF vp=0x601080
acptrchk: TRACE ptr=0x601080 msk=00000007 file='acbit/acbit3.c' lno=22
AFT vp=0x601081
acptrchk: TRACE ptr=0x601081 msk=00000007 file='acbit/acbit3.c' lno=29
acptrfault: pointer fault -- ptr=0x601081 file='acbit/acbit3.c' lno=29
```

I left off the AC code in this example. On your real target system, the dereference of `intptr` in `main` would/should fault on an alignment, but notice how much later that is in the execution timeline.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It looks like you have deliberately forced an unaligned access here by incrementing the pointer by a non-int size and then casting back to an int* (precisely what i do in my test that its working code) , which is actually the sort of errors i am trying to catch.  You may be right that this is not the best way to check this.  Others have suggested using perf or valgrind which might be nice if i can get it working.

Comment: I have _lots_ of debug experience for these sorts of things. If you can edit your question to describe the real problem in detail, I may be able to suggest something. Since you haven't trapped it, how do you know you have unaligned? Can you bound it to a number of variables or functions? Are you getting data corruption?

Comment: basically I a using my own custom allocator am preparing my code to run on an architecture that doesnt suport unaligned read/writes so I want to make sure my code will not break on that architecture.  I can trap unaligned read/write using either the asm , or via gdb but both cause SIGBUS which i cant continue from in gdb and im getting too many false positives from std library (in the sense that their implementation would be aligned access only on the target).  Ideally i guess i would like to use something like perf to show me callstacks that have misaligned but so far no dice.

Comment: thanks for this update, much appreciated and I like the idea of disabling the check before any library calls.  I have given up on perf for this  as it seems to show me garbage even for a simple program like the one you wrote.  Im using ocperf with misalign_mem_ref.loads and stores but either way the counters dont correlate at all.  If i record and look at the callstacks i get completely unrecognizable callstacks for these counters so i suspect either the counter doesnt work on my hardware/perf or it doesnt actually count what i think it counts :/ .

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to like it, but there is only one answer: don't link against the standard libraries. By changing that setting you have changed the ABI and the standard library doesn't like it. memcpy and friends are hand-written assembly so it's not a matter of compiler options to convince the compiler to do something else.