# Why does GAS inline assembly wrapped in a function generate different instructions for the caller than a pure assembly function

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, sse, gnu-assembler

I've been writing some basic functions using GCC's `asm` to practice for an actual application.

My functions `pretty`, `wrap`, and `pure` generate the same instructions to unpack a 64 bit integer into a 128 bit vector. `add1` and `add2` which call `pretty` and `wrap` respectively also generate the same instructions. But `add3` differs by saving its `xmm0` register by pushing it to the stack rather than by copying it to another `xmm` register. This I don't understand because the compiler can see the details of `pure` to know none of the other `xmm` registers will be clobbered.

Here is the C++

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m128i pretty(long long b) { return (__m128i){b,b}; }

__m128i wrap(long long b) {
    asm ("mov qword ptr [rsp-0x10], rdi\n"
         "vmovddup xmm0, qword ptr [rsp-0x10]\n"
         :
         : "r"(b)
         );
}

extern "C" __m128i pure(long long b);
asm (".text\n.global pure\n\t.type pure, @function\n"
     "pure:\n\t"
     "mov qword ptr [rsp-0x10], rdi\n\t"
     "vmovddup xmm0, qword ptr [rsp-0x10]\n\t"
     "ret\n\t"
     );

__m128i add1(__m128i in, long long in2) { return in + pretty(in2);}
__m128i add2(__m128i in, long long in2) { return in + wrap(in2);}
__m128i add3(__m128i in, long long in2) { return in + pure(in2);}
```

Compiled with `g++ -c  so.cpp -march=native   -masm=intel -O3 -fno-inline` and disassembled with `objdump -d -M intel so.o | c++filt`.

```
so.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <pure>:
   0:   48 89 7c 24 f0          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rdi
   5:   c5 fb 12 44 24 f0       vmovddup xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10]
   b:   c3                      ret
   c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000000010 <pretty(long long)>:
  10:   48 89 7c 24 f0          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rdi
  15:   c5 fb 12 44 24 f0       vmovddup xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10]
  1b:   c3                      ret
  1c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000000020 <wrap(long long)>:
  20:   48 89 7c 24 f0          mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rdi
  25:   c5 fb 12 44 24 f0       vmovddup xmm0,QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10]
  2b:   c3                      ret
  2c:   0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

0000000000000030 <add1(long long __vector(2), long long)>:
  30:   c5 f8 28 c8             vmovaps xmm1,xmm0
  34:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  38:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   3d <add1(long long __vector(2), long long)+0xd>
  3d:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  41:   c5 f9 d4 c1             vpaddq xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
  45:   c3                      ret
  46:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
  4d:   00 00 00

0000000000000050 <add2(long long __vector(2), long long)>:
  50:   c5 f8 28 c8             vmovaps xmm1,xmm0
  54:   48 83 ec 08             sub    rsp,0x8
  58:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   5d <add2(long long __vector(2), long long)+0xd>
  5d:   48 83 c4 08             add    rsp,0x8
  61:   c5 f9 d4 c1             vpaddq xmm0,xmm0,xmm1
  65:   c3                      ret
  66:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nop    WORD PTR cs:[rax+rax*1+0x0]
  6d:   00 00 00

0000000000000070 <add3(long long __vector(2), long long)>:
  70:   48 83 ec 18             sub    rsp,0x18
  74:   c5 f8 29 04 24          vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsp],xmm0
  79:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   7e <add3(long long __vector(2), long long)+0xe>
  7e:   c5 f9 d4 04 24          vpaddq xmm0,xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rsp]
  83:   48 83 c4 18             add    rsp,0x18
  87:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: Why did you define pure as extern "C", and not the others?  I suspect this is the reason for the difference, since you have forced the compiler to follow "C" calling convention.

Comment: It was a recommendation from this site (https://www.cs.uaf.edu/2011/fall/cs301/lecture/10_12_asm_c.html) and then I didn't have to worry about the name mangling.

Comment: The normal way to write `pretty` that doesn't depend on how `immintrin.h` defines `__m128i` is `_mm_set1_epi64x(b)`.  It compiles the same: gcc chooses store/`vmovddup` (worse latency, one fewer ALU uop), clang chooses `vmovq xmm0, rdi` / `vpbroadcastq xmm0, xmm0` (better latency, two port5 uops on Haswell)

Answer (score 2):

GCC does not understand assembly language.

Since `pure` is an external function it cannot determine which registers it alters so according to the ABI has to assume all the `xmm` registers are changed.

`wrap` has undefined behaviour as the `asm` statement clobbers `xmm0` and `[rsp-0x10]` which are not listed as clobbers or outputs (to a value which may or may not depend on `b`), and the function has no `return` statement.

Edit: The ABI does not apply to inline assembly, I expect your program will not work if you remove `-fno-inline` from the command line.

Comment: I was under the impression that the `xmm0` was OK but now that I think about it I see it; but I thought the `red zone` which I think `[rsp-0x10]` falls in has no guarantee about consistency across function calls. Wouldn't the lack of a return statement be covered by the calling convention which specifies `xmm0` as the return register; so that's where any caller of `wrap` will go to retrieve the value described by the function declaration?

Comment: I added `xmm0` and `memory` to the clobber list (does that fix it?) and the only change was the addition of the `vzeroupper` instruction immediately after `vmovddup`.

Comment: @chewsocks: you [must not clobber the red zone from inline asm](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34522750/224132), because there doesn't even seem to be a way to tell gcc that you want to do so.  If you want a value in memory for `vmovddup`, write it like this: `asm ("vmovddup %[result], %[src]" : [result] "=x" (output) : [src] "m" (b) ); return output;`.  Then gcc decides what memory to use, and can load directly from somewhere other than the stack.  It doesn't force gcc to load/store/reload if the value was already in memory.  [working example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/n9uEaO).

Comment: Also, @chewsocks: requiring `-masm=intel` to build is not common practice.  AT&T syntax isn't *that* bad.  Unless this is an in-house project that other people don't need to build, it's usually a good idea to just suck it up and use the standard AT&T syntax for GNU inline asm.  Or even use the dialect alternatives syntax:  `"vmovddup {%[src], %[result] | %[src], %[result]}"`, IIRC.