# Instruction SBIW in inline asm does not compile for arduino (atmega328p)

Tags: assembly, arduino, inline, atmega

I stumbled upon some strange compiling errors when using SBIW (Subtract Immediate from Word) in inline assembly. I want to use a register pair to do some simple 16-bit arithmetic (just incrementing/decrementing). I followed the instruction reference [Instruction-set, p. 119](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf/)  and used the code example shown on the page for my inline assembly:

```
asm volatile(
  "ldi r25, 0xff  \n"
  "ldi r24, 0xff  \n"
  "sbiw r25:r24,1 \n"
);
```

This snippet does not compile and throws the error: *register r24, r26, r28
or r30 required* Switching r25 and r24, I get:

```
asm volatile(
  "ldi r25, 0xff   \n"
  "ldi r24, 0xff   \n"
  "sbiw r24:r25, 1 \n"
);
```

still not compiling with an error *`,' required*, leading to:

```
asm volatile(
  "ldi r25, 0xff   \n"
  "ldi r24, 0xff   \n"
  "sbiw r24, 1     \n"
);
```

which is compiling without an error. What am I overseeing here? Might add that I am not that versatile with asm, so maybe I just got the documentation wrong.

On a sidenote: are sbiw/adiw good choices for simple 16 bit arithmetic? Thanks for your input!

Comment: Nothing, your assembler simply wants that syntax. `sbiw` automatically operates on consecutive registers, so it's not really necessary to give both.

Comment: It's usually better to let the compiler do as much work as possible.  Tell it you want 0xff in two C variables that you use as read-write operands.  I hope you're just simplifying to remove your input/output operands for the SO post...

Comment: @PeterCordes Indeed, I removed input/output/clobbers for simplicity sake. But I'll keep your hint in mind. Cheers, also to Jester

Comment: I've written some answers about using GNU C inline asm to make code that doesn't suck.  Most of it is applicable to non-x86, even though all the examples are x86.  I put a link collection [at the end of an answer where it seemed relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520013/using-base-pointer-register-in-c-inline-asm/34522750#34522750).