# Breaking a stack/call frame information chain on ELF/Linux?

Tags: x86-64, dwarf, stack-unwinding

I'm trying to do a rather niche thing which is essentially breaking the `CFI` (Call Frame Information in DWARF EH info) and `rbp` & `rsp` links between frames. Main reason for that is that is that past a certain point in thread control flow I want to do  a call continuation which is basically a one-way tailcall combined with a yield which should clean up the stack and then return to the top of the stack ready to be executed again at the continuation point.

Here is the idea in principle, which works as long as I keep the lines that mess with the stack commented out:

```
    /*
     * x86_64 SysV:
     *   rdi, rsi, rds, rcx, r8, r9, xmm0-xmm7
     */
    __asm {
        mov  rax, TCB
        mov  rax, qword ptr [rax] OSThreadControlBlock.StartFn;
        call rax;
        mov  rax, 0;
        // end of stack
        //push rax;
        //push rax;
        //push rbx;
        // last "real" frame
        //push rbp;
        //mov  rbp, rsp;
        //push rbx;
        // make the call
        mov  rdi, RL;
        lea  rax, qword ptr __OS_RUNLOOP_START__;
        call rax;
        // trap if it returns
        //int  3;
    }
```

I'm aware of the general principles behind SP/BP registers, I'm specifically using `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. My question is, after having spent hours trying to get it to work, what am I missing? It seems that any alteration to the stack layout, even as simple as a push before a call while keeping it aligned will cause a snowball crash starting with something like this (custom signal handler):

```
Received fatal signal: Segmentation fault (11) [thread: 10298 ctl-thrd]
 * Unknown error at address 0x0 Regs:
   %rip=0x00000000003E2D91 %rbp=0x00007F820A547EA8 %rsp=0x00007F820A547DE8 %rax=0x00007F820A547DE8 %rbx=0x00007F820A547F38
   %rdi=0x00000000002121E1 %rsi=0x000000000000007B %rcx=0x000000000000000A  %r8=0x0000000000000900  %r9=0x00007F820A5490C0
```

The ABI in question is `libc++`/`libc++abi` on `x86_64` Linux, with a LLVM/Clang 6.0.X based toolchain. I tried practically everything, I know the above looks weird but it's an MS extension for inline assembly, I checked multiple times in disassemblies that it generates perfectly sane code. As far as I understand this is some weird conflict between CFI and frame pointer based stuff but I'm not that amazingly good at `x86_64` so I'm not really sure what I'm missing.  I know the unwinding process is meant to be terminated by a sentinel (null SP/FP on the last frame) but at this point I'm honestly lost because  even the debugger gets completely thrown off by this.

If anyone has any suggestions that would be really appreciated, I tried various things but the core problem is the same, as soon as I touch the stack, even if I return it to normal, everything goes haywire. Clobber beyond the asm block doesn't matter since the last call is not meant to conventionally return. One thing I did notice is that it seems this is somehow related to TLVs but I'm  not sure how since NPTL is meant to configure that.

Any help or suggestions would me immensely appreciated.

**Edit:**

Looks like this comment from Valgrind may explain what is happening:

```
/* NB 9 Sept 07.  There is a nasty kludge here in all these CALL_FN_
   macros.  In order not to trash the stack redzone, we need to drop
   %rsp by 128 before the hidden call, and restore afterwards.  The
   nastyness is that it is only by luck that the stack still appears
   to be unwindable during the hidden call - since then the behaviour
   of any routine using this macro does not match what the CFI data
   says.  Sigh.

   Why is this important?  Imagine that a wrapper has a stack
   allocated local, and passes to the hidden call, a pointer to it.
   Because gcc does not know about the hidden call, it may allocate
   that local in the redzone.  Unfortunately the hidden call may then
   trash it before it comes to use it.  So we must step clear of the
   redzone, for the duration of the hidden call, to make it safe.

   Probably the same problem afflicts the other redzone-style ABIs too
   (ppc64-linux, ppc32-aix5, ppc64-aix5); but for those, the stack is
   self describing (none of this CFI nonsense) so at least messing
   with the stack pointer doesn't give a danger of non-unwindable
   stack. */
```

Comment: Possible important:  I haven't tried clang's MSVC-style inline asm syntax, but with GNU style, it's not safe to clobber the red-zone from inline asm. ([Using base pointer register in C++ inline asm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34520013)).  Thus, unless you do `sub rsp, 128` before you `push` or `call`, you're potentially stepping on stuff the compiler is keeping below RSP.

Comment: BTW, what's the point of `lea  rax, qword ptr __OS_RUNLOOP_START__` / `call rax`?  Why would you want a 32-bit sign-extended absolute address (a `[disp32]` encoding)?  Why not `call rel32`, i.e. `call __OS_RUNLOOP_START__`.

Comment: Terminology: I think your TLV is "thread local variables".  If so, the usual terminology (on Linux for sure, and in general I think) is TLS (Thread Local Storage).

Comment: Which instruction is faulting?  Use `gdb` to find out and make a [mcve].  Are you throwing an exception, and faulting in the stack-walking code because you did stuff to the stack without CFI?  Although if everything was compiled with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, it might actually be using that, I'm not sure.  The way you could break that chain is to make a fake stack frame with a NULL-terminator for the linked list of RBP values, like you do with `_start` when it does `xor ebp,ebp` / `call something` and `something` pushes the zeroed RBP after the return address.

Comment: @PeterCordes Haven't thought of the redzone, will try with keeping it in mind this time but yes this is essentially the same as inline assembly GNU style except I find it more convenient to write.  This isn't really formal MSVC-style anyway since I don't believe they ever supported it on x86_64.  And the `lea` thing was just a test, nothing faults right there and then, it runs and then crashes in an odd place, seemingly related to trying to access a TLS variable. I don't really have backtraces to go on so I'm just looking at `rip` and looking there with IDA.

Comment: You don't need a backtrace to look at register values at the crash site and figure out locally which reg had a bogus value.  And you can probably tell if it's in a function that called your context-switch thing, or if it inlined there and the bogus reg value was reloaded from the red zone.  Maybe build the compilation unit containing your inline asm with `-mno-redzone`, or your whole project that way just to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Most faults sampled across my various trial and error runs of shuffling things around have shown that the fault was around the point where it was using `fs` with a negative offset likely to access thread data (at least that's where NPTL is supposed to store it, I believe the actual address is near the bottom of the thread's stack).